# How can I query the db to access current post information?

Tags: database, query, id

Alright y'all. I want to dynamically display the information of the 2 most current posts to the screen. So far I have only been able to get results by hard coding the ID into the query. Is there a way to retrieve this data dynamically?

```
query_posts('showposts=2'); 

 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $x = get_the_ID(); 
echo $x;
$postStuff = $wpdb->get_row('select * from wp_posts where ID = "$x", ARRAY_A);
print_r($postStuff); ?>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2'); 

while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php

 global $post;
 print_r($post);  // <-- this is your postStuff

?>

<?php endwhile;?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Normally, you dont't need to globalize the post. There are helper functions that should be used instead to fetch information from the current post

Comment: yep, the helper functions are called template tags. The post related ones are here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags#Post_tags

Comment: One Trick... you did it! Well done.